# npm request with headers and auth

Tags: node.js, curl

I am trying to access an API using "request" npm. This API requires header "content-type" and a basic authentication. here is what I've done so far.

```
var request = require('request');
var options = {
  url: 'https://XXX/index.php?/api/V2/get_case/2',
  headers: {
    'content-type': 'application/json'
  },

};
request.get(options, function(error, response, body){
console.log(body);
}

).auth("dummyemail@abc.com","password",false);
```

upon executing this using Node , I am getting an error that says invalid username and password. I've validated the same API, authentication and header using CURL with the command below and it gave an expected HTTP response.

curl -X GET -H "content-type: application/json"   -u dummyemail@abc.com:password "https://XXX/index.php?/api/V2/get_case/2"

Please suggest the right way to code request with auth and header.

---

Here is my update code

```
var auth = new Buffer("dummy@gmail.com" + ':' + "password").toString('base64');
     var req = {
                    host: 'https://URL',
                    path: 'index.php?/api/v2/get_case/2',
                    method: 'GET',
                    headers: {
                        Authorization: 'Basic ' + auth,
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                              }
                };
    request(req,callback);
    function callback(error, response, body) {
      console.log(body);
    }
```

I am seeing 'undefined' in my console. can you help me here?

Answer (score 27):

Here is how it worked for me

```
 var auth = new Buffer(user + ':' + pass).toString('base64');
 var req = {
     host: 'https://XXX/index.php?/api/V2/get_case/2',
     path: path,
     method: 'GET',
     headers: {
         Authorization: 'Basic ' + auth,
         'Content-Type': 'application/json'
     }
 };
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Here is what I've tried with your suggestion.

Comment: @Praveen Kumar: It seems to me that Katerina's response was exactly correct and should be accepted as the answer

Answer (score 10):

```
request(url, {
  method: "POST",
  auth: {
    user: this.user,
    pass: this.pass
  }
}, function (error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
      console.log('body:', body);
    } else {
      console.log('error', error, response && response.statusCode);
    }
});
```